# RecyclerView Adapter get unset in ViewPager on swipe the framgment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

I am using a simple ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter as an adapter, where each fragment has a RecyclerView with some item.

**Adapter**

```
public class HomeScreenPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> pageInfo;

    public HomeScreenPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, Context context, List<Integer> pageInfo) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        this.context = context;
        this.pageInfo = pageInfo;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return HomeScreenFragment.getInstance(pageInfo.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageInfo.size();
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
 public class HomeScreenFragment extends Fragment {
    
        private static final String PAGE_TITLE = "pageTitle";
        private RecyclerView recyclerViewHome;
        private ApplicationAdapter applicationAdapter;
        private DragLayer dragLayer = null;
        Set<String> imageSet;
        int pageNumber;
    
        public static HomeScreenFragment getInstance(int pStrPageTitle) {
            HomeScreenFragment homeScreenFragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(PAGE_TITLE, pStrPageTitle);
            homeScreenFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return homeScreenFragment;
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            imageSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            return LayoutInflater.from(ExceptionHandlerApplication.getAppContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_screen_fragment, container, false);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(PAGE_TITLE);
            recyclerViewHome = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHome);
            recyclerViewHome.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManagerWrapper(ExceptionHandlerApplication.getAppContext(), numCount));
            imageSet.clear();
            imageSet.addAll(Util.filterImagesByPageNumber(pageNumber));
            updateList();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Log.d("ApplicationAdapter","HomeScreenFragment OnResume startCount is "+applicationAdapter.getItemCount() +" for "+ pageNumber);
 Log.d("ApplicationAdapter","HomeScreenFragment onResume ==> " + pageNumber + " ==applicationAdapter SIZE " + applicationAdapter.getItemCount() + " ====> allowedApps " + allowedApps.size());
            if (recyclerViewHome != null && applicationAdapter != null && applicationAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                Log.d("ApplicationAdapter","HomeScreenFragment forceRefresh "+ pageNumber);
               // this will fix the issue if we reset the adapter, else it will throw excpetion.
                updateList();
            }
           
        }
    
        private void updateList() {
            try {
                applicationAdapter = new ApplicationAdapter(getContext(), allowedApps, recyclerViewHome, dragLayer);
                recyclerViewHome.setAdapter(applicationAdapter);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Logger.logInfo("GridLayoutManagerWrapper Error Activity");
                Logger.logError(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Facing an issue**,

when we swipe some Fragments in ViewPager and came back to the previous fragment it's throwing the exception IndexOutOfBound on the scroll of recycler view.

when I debugged the issue, **adapter.getItemSize()** returning 0 in onResume but list **imageSet.size()** has a total image count.

Not able to identify why data is unbinding from RecyclerView when we switched to another fragment, the same thing happened with ViewPager2 also.

**Work Around i have found**  if we set the recyclerView adapter again, it's working fine.

Comment: I think the problem is in that HomeScreenPagerAdapter 's getItemPosition there you return POSITION_NONE which means whe swipe viewpager will create a new fragment again, maybe you should return POSITION_UNCHANGED.

Comment: Probably you need to post the stacktrace report

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the ViewPager's off screen limit? This controls how many pages are retained either side of the current page. Set the off screen page limit to some high number and see if that works. Use it like this: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(X);`, where X is your high page limit integer.

Comment: On your ViewPagerAdapter set the viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pageInfo.size()); this will not destroy your old view.